# Working with promise - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to rewrite this code, to get the desired o/p.
I would like to use the AgentReply object after filling in the data.
Inside the switch case, this object has data. But once outside, it is null again. Understood that it is because of the async, 
But what should I do, to be able to use 'AgentReply' once it has data.

```
$scope.ActionItems = function (actionItem) {
var AgentReply = {};
switch (actionItem) {
 case "SendOTP":
                var SentStatus = "";                
                DataFactory.SendOTP('39487539847')
                .then(function (response) {
                    SentStatus = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
                    SendOTPFailed();                        
                }, function (error) {
                });                
                break;
}/*End of switch*/
function SendOTPFailed(){
  if (SentStatus == "200") {
    AgentReply = {
      IsCustomer: false,
      UserText: "Request Failed.",
     }                            
  }
}

if (Object.keys(AgentReply).length > 0) {
   //do something with AgentReply  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a function in to where the `AgentReply` is available, and define it underneath, ie:

```
$scope.ActionItems = function (actionItem) {
    var AgentReply = {};

    switch (actionItem) {
        case "SendOTP":

            var SentStatus = "";                
            DataFactory.SendOTP('39487539847')
                .then(function (response) {
                    SentStatus = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
                    if (SentStatus == "200") {
                        AgentReply = {
                            IsCustomer: false,
                            UserText: "Request Failed.",
                        }                            
                    }
                    doSomethingWithAgentReply(AgentReply);
                }, function (error) {
            });                
            break;
    }
    console.log(AgentReply); //null here

    function doSomethingWithAgentReply(reply) {

        if (Object.keys(reply).length > 0) {
            //do something with AgentReply  
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way, I can do it within $scope.ActionItems itself

Comment: @Qwerty Is there a reason why you'd need to?

Comment: @Qwerty It is in the `$scope.ActionItems` now, if that's what you meant?

Comment: I followed ur way, but the same prob. The `Object.keys(reply).length..` is a common fn. for many other switch cases. Updated the Question. Please have a look

Comment: @Qwerty Are you sure `SentStatus` equals 200? And are you sure you are supposed to be using `JSON.parse` twice on the `response.data`?

Comment: Yes. Sure about both. But I resolved it but extracting the new function outside $scope.ActionItems as you suggested earlier. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use this code :

```
if (Object.keys(AgentReply).length > 0) {
   //do something with AgentReply  
  }
}
```

Outside the `.then()` function :

```
DataFactory.SendOTP('39487539847')
  .then(function (response) {

  })
```

You can try this:

```
$scope.ActionItems = function (actionItem) {

var def = jQuery.Deferred();

var AgentReply = {};
switch (actionItem) {
  case "SendOTP":
    var SentStatus = "";                
    DataFactory.SendOTP('39487539847')
      .then(function (response) {
        SentStatus = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        if (SentStatus == "200") {
          AgentReply = {
            IsCustomer: false,
            UserText: "Request Failed.",
          }                            
          def.resolve(AgentReply);
        }

        console.log(AgentReply); //available here
     }, function (error) {
        def.reject(error);
   });

   return def.promise();

   break;
}


//console.log(AgentReply); //null here
//if (Object.keys(AgentReply).length > 0) {
   //do something with AgentReply  
//  }
//}
// This is unusable in this case.
```

The usage is:

```
var someActionItem = 'SomeActionItemInfo';

$scope.ActionItems(someActionItem)
  .then(function(agentReply) {
    if (Object.keys(agentReply).length > 0) {
      //do something with agentReply
    }
  }, function(error));
```

**EDIT**:

`$scope.ActionItems` is the same function. What happening when you using promise?

First you defining the deffer object. `var def = jQuery.Deferred()`. This object is at jQuery, but all frameworks/libraryies that support promise working at the same way.

As you see, you returning `def.promise()`. That is the object which contain `.then` property. Because of that obj you can use `$scope.ActionItems().then()` method. That actually make `def.promise()`.

And inside your async code (this code that consuming some time and it's not executed immediately) you defining `def.resolve()` or `def.reject()`.

When the work is done. You calling `def.resolve(withSomeData)` and this will activate `.then()` method to the `$scope.ActionItems`.

For example:

```
var foo = null;

function doPromise() {
  var def = jQuery.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function(){
    foo = 2;

    def.resolve(foo + 1) // This will call the .then() method with foo + 1

  }, 500);

  return def.promise();
}

doPromise();
console.log(foo) // foo = null here. cuz the function waiting 500ms.

// Here the .then() method will be executed after ~500+ ms.
doPromise().then(function(fooValue) {
  console.log(fooValue) // foo value = 3 here. cuz function is done
});
```

Comment: is `$scope.ActionItems(someActionItem)` another function. I am unable to understand what happens after `def.promise();break;` from your code please.